# Count Rows in Multiple Tables by ID and Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm facing a task that I am unable to solve.

At first, I have a mysql database where I have  specifics tables for each type of user generated content like blog, photo and videos. These tables are similar, generally as follow:

```
USER_ID | TIMESTAMP | CONTENT_ID | CONTENT
1       | 1364978606|      1     | video_url_1
1       | 1364978606|      2     | video_url_2
```

Each row contain a single content posted.

The question is: I need count in each table the number of "rows" for each USER_ID, filtering by a timestamp period (between two timestamp). After I need to add the count of row by USER_ID (total of count in video plus total of count in photo plus total of count in blog) and display only the five highest results excluding one or two USER_ID that are admin user.

Does not seem very difficult, but I could not write any syntax that works yet.

Comment: can you possibly add your desired output?

Answer (score 1):

```
select  user_id
,       count(*)
from    (
        select  user_id
        ,       timestamp
        from    video
        union all
        select  user_id
        ,       timestamp
        from    photo
        union all
        select  user_id
        ,       timestamp
        from    blog
        ) SubQueryAlias
where   user_id not in (6,7)  -- assuming admin users 6 and 7
        and timestamp between '2013-01-01' and '2013-04-01'
group by
        user_id
order by
        count(*) desc
limit   5
```

Comment: `+1` you need to also add the `TIMESTAMP` for every select in your subquery  in order to complete the requirements. once timestamp is added, you can now count the date range, `SUM(CASE WHEN timestamp between xx AND yy THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

Comment: @JW웃: Thanks!  I think it is OK to apply the timestamp filter in the outer `where` clause.

Comment: you're right. `:)` I was thinking the other way because I misunderstood the question and that's why I read it again. hehe

Answer (score 0):

First, get all the rows you want:

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE user_id = ? AND timestamp < ? AND timestamp > ?;
```

Then, in PHP, assuming you use mysqli, you can just call [num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) on a results object:

```
$numVideos = $results->num_rows;
```

If you want to do this for multiple users, the lazy way would be a `foreach` loop with database calls inside it, the correct way would be to fetch all results between the timestamps as associated arrays, then transverse arrays.

Comment: Umm, what? He's storing timestamps in seconds since epoch format.

Comment: Two `?`s does not signify two identical values.

Comment: Duh!  Ok.  I'll remove the comments :)